# URL Rewrite/Redirect to mobile pages in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm working on a mobile version of an ASP.NET website and need help with navigating to the mobile pages.

I'm currently using URL Rewrite Module 2.0 and my goal is to have the URL displayed to the user in the form of `m.example.com`

Here are some examples:

```
input url:
www.example.com/mobile
m.example.com

uses:
/Mobile/Default.aspx

url shown:
m.example.com    


input url:
www.example.com/mobile/contact.aspx
m.example.com/contact.aspx

uses:
/Mobile/Contact.aspx

url shown:
m.example.com/contact.aspx
```

I already have rules that will remove `/default.aspx` and add `www.` when needed, so I can guarantee those conditions.

I'm thinking that I would do a redirect to the `/mobile/` page, then rewrite as `m.`, unless there is a better way to have IIS 7.5 know which aspx page to use when it sees the `m.` url.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here. You seem to have a clear idea of what you want and how to use rewrite rules.

Comment: @mason I'm new to the Rewrite stuff, so I want to verify some things. It seems strange that if a user goes to `m.example.com/contact.aspx` I would have to redirect them to `www.example.com/mobile/contact.aspx` in order to load the page, then have to rewrite the url back as `m.example.com/contact.aspx` before showing it. I would think there is an easy way for IIS to say `m.` pages to look at the `/mobile/` folder.

Comment: There is an easier way. Don't bother with mobile URL's. They confuse things. What if someone with a mobile device sends a link to a desktop user? Now the desktop user is going to have a mobile experience. Not good. Instead, keep everything on the same URL and just swap out views based on the screen size, with an option for desktop users to use mobile views and vice versa. Microsoft has a package that makes this all very easy, [Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls/).

Comment: The documentation for the above package is [here](https://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @mason Since I don't need to convert the entire website, and even the pages that are converted don't have nearly the same content, I'm better off having separate pages. The Marketing department is making the decisions on how they want the URLs to look, and I need to make it happen. Is there a way to easily trim the first folder name off the URL using a rewrite?